# Best way to pass server (c# / Razor) values into an AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor, dotnetnuke

We use DNN and often need to pass a few context specific values (like page id or module-on-page-id) into an AngularJS app. We've developed our own conventions how to do this, but would like to hear from others how they approach this to find a best practice.

So basically the situation is that the server-page has information needed by the JS. Using WebAPI is not an option, as these values are known in the page, but not in a separate request. Things I've seen so far have been:

1. Use in-view-razor like `href="@Tab.TabId/{{...}}"` (I don't like this)
2. Place the values in the ng-init like `ng-init="config = { prop1: '@Tab.TabId' }"`
3. Create a separate `<script>` tag where we generate a module on the fly containing these values so `angular.module("config", []).constant('prop1', '@Tab.TabId')`
4. Create a json with razor in the page somewhere and inject all of it as a module into the app using a generic code which does the same as #3, just with cleaner code re-use.

I've seen all these and have also used all. Currently we avoid #1 as we believe it's not good to mix templating languages and because it doesn't allow externalizing parts of the view. So basically we use #2 as for quick-and-simple (and a bit dirty) + #3/#4 for larger projects.

Do you have a better way, or which way would you prefer?

Answer (score 0):

We are using variant #4.

This has the advantage that the JSON defines the exact interface for the config needed by the JS module. And Razor is great to generate URLs using `@Url.Action`.

Answer (score 0):

we use NewtonSoft and do JSONConvert.SerializeObject(ObjectName) and then pass it over as a Session from the controller and then use @Html.Raw(ObjectName) and its a JSON Object that can be utilized easily in javascript...

Comment: This doesn't have any effect on the described url encoding issues